# updating GWT(GXT) Buttoncell in a grid at runtime

Tags: gwt, gxt

I am  creating a button cell in GXT Grid,
and adding the cell in my grid column like this

```
  myCol.setCell(getButtonCell());
```

Now all cells are drawn , after that depends on the server call i want to update my cell with a new Value of MyDTO.

So on my RPC success , I want to call this render for all of my cells and update there values.
How can i achieve this.

```
public ButtonCell<MyDTO> getButtonCell()
{
    ButtonCell<MyDTO> cellTest = new ButtonCell<MyDTO>()
    {

        @Override
        public void render(Context context, MyDTO value, SafeHtmlBuilder 
      sb)
        {
           sb.appendHtmlConstant(value.getName());
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Sencha GXT grid uses a ListStore. To show new data inside the grid, the store needs to be updated. This can be done by calling `store.addAll(theNewDataList)`. Keep in mind to clear the store before adding new values.

Updating the store will force the grid to redraw. During the redraw, the `render`-method of the `ButtonCell` will be called. To change the layout of the button, implement inside the `render`-method what you want to do.

This is an example from the Sencha GXT Explorer (https://examples.sencha.com/gxt/examples/#ExamplePlace:grid_aggregationgrid):

```java
      final NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getFormat("0.00");
      changeColumn.setCell(new PropertyDisplayCell<Double>(new DoublePropertyEditor(numberFormat)) {
        @Override
        public void render(com.google.gwt.cell.client.Cell.Context context, Double value, SafeHtmlBuilder sb) {
          String style = value < 0 ? "red" : "green";
          sb.appendHtmlConstant("<span style='color:" + style + "'>");
          super.render(context, value, sb);
          sb.appendHtmlConstant("</span>");
        }
      });
```

In case the value is less than 0 it will render a red string otherwise a green one.

Hope that helps.

Comment: this answer is correct ,in addition - if you want to also change the style of it - you can setStyleName as well - which will override the old css of the element